# HTML email liquid layout breaking in Gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email, email-client

I have created a HTML email that has a particular layout issue when viewed in Gmail on a web browser, and on the Android App (Gmail). I've been unable to track down the offending code so far, and cannot understand why Gmail is splitting the HTML email in two past a certain point and placing the content in what appear to be two separate columns.

If anyone can help suggest a solution or what is the cause of the issue, along with a potential fix then this would be much appreciated.

HTML viewable here:

https://jsfiddle.net/59bd2z0L/

Screenshots of issue here (Gmail web browser):

[image]

Screenshots of issue here (Gmail Android App):

[image]

Source HTML here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
map area {outline:none;}
</style>
<title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<center>

<font style="font-size:13px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Header goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.<media><br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a style="color:#000000;" href="&&&">click here</a>.</font><br /><br />

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td width="640">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="right">
<font style="font-size:16px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"><a style="color:#000000;" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></font><br />
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td></td><td width="640">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">


<tr><td>

<!-- Image Section -->
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/gold-te-header.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:500px;" alt="" border="0" /></a></center>
<!-- End Image Section -->

<!-- Image Section -->
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-logo.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:500px;" alt="" border="0" /></a></center>
<!-- End Image Section -->

</td></tr>

<tr><td height="10" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<!-- Menu Section -->
<tr><td><center><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-women-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:121px;" alt="Women" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-men-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:81px;" alt="Men" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-uni-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:116px;" alt="Unisex" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-foot-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:165px;" alt="Footwear" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/clear-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:157px;" alt="Clearance" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr></table></center></td></tr>
<!-- End Menu Section -->

<tr><td height="10" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<!-- Image Section -->
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork1.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Image Section -->

<!-- Image Section -->
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork2.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Image Section -->

<!-- Image Section -->
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork3.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Image Section -->

<tr><td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<!-- Large Live Text Section -->
<tr><td>
<center>
<font style="font-size:19px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
<strong>Size 19 Live text:</strong> et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum.</strong>
</font>
</center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Large Live Text Section -->

<tr><td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<!-- Image Section -->
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork4cta.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Image Section -->

<tr><td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<!-- Image Section -->
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork5.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Image Section -->

<!-- Image Section -->
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork6cta.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Image Section -->

<tr><td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<!-- Letter Text Section -->
<tr><td>
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td width="3%"></td><td width="94%">
<font style="font-size:16px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur

</font>
</center>
</td><td width="3%"></td></tr></table>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Letter Text Section -->

<tr><td height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<!-- Grey Background Section -->
<tr><td bgcolor="#eff0f2" height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#eff0f2">
<center>
<font style="font-size:19px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</strong><br /><br /><br />
</font>
<font style="font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
</font>
</center>
</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#eff0f2" height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<!-- End Grey Background Section -->

<tr><td height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<!-- Double Banner -->
<tr><td><center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/email-ecat.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:320px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-banner-r.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:320px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center></td></tr>
<!-- End Double Banner -->

<!-- USP Section -->
<tr><td><center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-locator.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:280px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-size.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:280px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-care.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:280px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-returns.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:280px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center></td></tr>
<!-- End USP Section -->

<!-- Social Section -->
<tr><td><center><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-fbook.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:196px;" alt="Facebook" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-pin.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:78px;" alt="Pinterest" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-twi.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:77px;" alt="Twitter" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-google.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:96px;" alt="Google+" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-blog.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:192px;" alt="Blog" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr></table></center></td></tr>
<!-- End Social Section -->

<!-- Bottom Menu -->
<tr><td>
<center><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-viewmore.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="View More" /></center>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-women-bot.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Women" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-men-bot.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Men" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-uni-bot.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Unisex" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-foot-bot.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Footwear" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-security.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Clearance" border="0" /></a></center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Bottom Menu -->

<!-- Security Banners -->
<tr><td>
<center><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-1.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Security" /></center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End Security Banners -->

<!-- T&Cs -->
<tr><td>
<center>
<font style="font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"><br />

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur

</font>
</center>
</td></tr>
<!-- End T&Cs -->

</table>
</td><td></td></tr></table>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check your code first, there are many problems with it; https://validator.w3.org/check. Also i allways prefer Zurb Ink for HTML mailing themes; http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html

Comment: The W3C violations are due to building HTML email code for older clients support. Sadly due to workplace restraints the luxury of using Foundation for Emails, but thank you for your recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many HTML tag placement errors in your code. Here's the corrected code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    map area {
      outline: none;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <center>

    <font style="font-size:13px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Header goes here Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.<br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a style="color:#000000;" href="&&&">click here</a>.
    </font>
    <br />
    <br />

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="640">

          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
              <td align="right">
                <font style="font-size:16px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"><a style="color:#000000;" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></font>
                <br />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="640">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">


            <tr>
              <td>

                <!-- Image Section -->
                <center>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/gold-te-header.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:500px;" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                </center>
                <!-- End Image Section -->

                <!-- Image Section -->
                <center>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-logo.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:500px;" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                </center>
                <!-- End Image Section -->

              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td height="10" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Menu Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-women-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:121px;" alt="Women" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-men-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:81px;" alt="Men" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-uni-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:116px;" alt="Unisex" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-foot-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:165px;" alt="Footwear" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/clear-top.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:157px;" alt="Clearance" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Menu Section -->

            <tr>
              <td height="10" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Image Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork1.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Image Section -->

            <!-- Image Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork2.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Image Section -->

            <!-- Image Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork3.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Image Section -->

            <tr>
              <td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Large Live Text Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <font style="font-size:19px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
                    <strong>Size 19 Live text:</strong> et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum.
                  </font>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Large Live Text Section -->

            <tr>
              <td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Image Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork4cta.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Image Section -->

            <tr>
              <td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Image Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork5.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Image Section -->

            <!-- Image Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-artwork6cta.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:640px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Image Section -->

            <tr>
              <td height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Letter Text Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="3%"></td>
                      <td width="94%">
                        <font style="font-size:16px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">

                          Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
                          sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
                          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem
                          vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur

                        </font>

                      </td>
                      <td width="3%"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Letter Text Section -->

            <tr>
              <td height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Grey Background Section -->
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#eff0f2" height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#eff0f2">
                <center>
                  <font style="font-size:19px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
                    <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</strong><br /><br /><br />
                  </font>
                  <font style="font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
                  </font>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#eff0f2" height="20" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Grey Background Section -->

            <tr>
              <td height="30" style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Double Banner -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/email-ecat.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:320px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-banner-r.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:320px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Double Banner -->

            <!-- USP Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-locator.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:280px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-size.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:280px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-care.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:280px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-returns.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:280px;" alt="Header goes here using promotional code <media>" border="0" /></a>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End USP Section -->

            <!-- Social Section -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-fbook.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:196px;" alt="Facebook" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-pin.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:78px;" alt="Pinterest" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-twi.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:77px;" alt="Twitter" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-google.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:96px;" alt="Google+" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-blog.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:192px;" alt="Blog" border="0" /></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Social Section -->

            <!-- Bottom Menu -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-viewmore.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="View More" /></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-women-bot.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Women" border="0" /></a>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-men-bot.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Men" border="0" /></a>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-uni-bot.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Unisex" border="0" /></a>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-foot-bot.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Footwear" border="0" /></a>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <a href=""><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-security.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Clearance" border="0" /></a>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Bottom Menu -->

            <!-- Security Banners -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center><img src="http://e76511c942b88eacf86b-059234da599e889c40c5d41b924fda9f.r7.cf3.rackcdn.com/responsive-email-1.jpg" width="100%" style="max-width:639px;" alt="Security" /></center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End Security Banners -->

            <!-- T&Cs -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <center>
                  <font style="font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;"><br /> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim
                    ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
                    velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?
                    Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur

                  </font>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- End T&Cs -->

          </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Use it and let me know if it works :)